# How to extract only mp3 files from a ZIP archive

Tags: python, zip

I have this code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import glob
inp = raw_input("Specify a ZIP archive to extract:")
with ZipFile(inp) as zf:
    zf.extractall()
```

It works fine because it extracts all the files but how do I extract all the `.mp3` files in the archive that the user specifies.

Comment: By "mp3 files", do you mean "files whose names end in `.mp3`", or do you mean "files that are valid mp3 files regardless of their filename"? The former is easier.

Comment: any could do, the name of the mp3 is different in every archive and there's guaranteed to be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract just the MP3 files from a ZIP archive, you could do the following:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

zip_file = r"c:\folder\myzip.zip"
target_folder = r"C:\Users\Fred\Desktop"

with ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as my_zip:
    mp3_files = [name for name in my_zip.namelist() if os.path.splitext(name)[1].lower() == '.mp3']
    my_zip.extractall(target_folder, mp3_files)
```

The list of files inside the ZIP file can be obtained using the [`namelist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) function. With this you can filter just those files ending with an `mp3` extension. The [`extractall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) function lets you pass a list of all of the files you want to extract (it defaults to all files).

Answer (score 1):

You could [get a list of the names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) of the members in the list, and only [extract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) those ending with the suffix `.mp3`.

Comment: @Sol: yes since 2.6. Guess what single character to change in Joachim's URLs, to find the Python 2 documentation ;-)

Comment: Stupid question, but how do you extract the files only ending with .mp3?

Comment: @SolAnderson Try printing e.g. `'foo.mp3'[-4:]`. Experiment! :)

Comment: But the mp3 is different in every archive. So how can I extract any mp3(s) present in the zip file.

Comment: @SolAnderson If the names doesn't necessarily end in `.mp3` then my answer won't work. It's only based on name and name alone. If you want to have some heuristic to recognize all files as MPEG Layer-III files, then you actually *need* to extract all files, test them somehow (I think there are modules for file identification) and remove all non-mp3 files.